# How to ensure that a user is a member of a group using Puppet

Tags: puppet

Importantly, I want nothing more or less than this. I want to manage only a limited set of groups for a limited set of users, without ever changing any of their main groups or removing any other group memberships. Is this possible without resorting to a lot of `exec`s? I'm running Puppet 6 without a master.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is [not possible in Puppet itself](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3745) yet.